# Transfer dotnetnuke database data to new server

Tags: dotnetnuke

I was given a dotnetnuke v4.9.5.5 database (sql-express about 300MB) and I am trying to get it up and running on a different server. I have tried:

- Installing the 4.9 version and

  - loading the database into the app_data folder
  - loading the database through the SQL page under the host login (forwards to 404 page...)
- installing the 5.x version and

  - loading the database into the app_data folder
  - loading the database through the SQL page under the host login (forwards to 404 page... again..)

All of which fail. I cannot find any support on this topic at all. What is the correct way to go about this?

**EDIT: wrong info please close..**

Comment: You have the database but no site files? Or are you trying to separate the database from the web server and put it into it's own non-express version of SQL on another server?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good blog on the topic [HOW TO: Move a DotNetNuke installation](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Community/Blogs/tabid/825/EntryId/1293/HOW-TO-Move-a-DotNetNuke-installation.aspx) .

The basics are:

- Copy all the files and the database, the two are closely tied together.
- Update the connection string in the web.config.
- Update the portal alias' in the PortalAlias table.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the rest of the site files, it may be very difficult. While the database will contain most of the site content, you may be missing some important pieces like skin files, module files, and content files.

So, the first thing you should do is see if you can get the files zipped up and sent to you. If so, it should be fairly easy to get the site up and running. You may have to update the ConnectionStrings in the web.config but otherwise it should run as it.

If you can't get the original files, you could try installing version 4.9.5 of DotNetNuke and replacing the supplied database with the database you were given. You'll need to post the error messages you get if it doesn't work out or consult someone with solid DotNetNuke experience.